# WSO2 developer studio doesn't show API Resource Properties tab

Tags: wso2, ei, wso2-integration-studio

I've installed WSO2 Developer Studio and restarted Eclipse but when I tried to get Properties Tab only get this:

[Properties????](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0bgA.png)

It should be like this:

[API Resource Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Rr5.png)

What do I have to do?  Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using the Eclipse Oxygen package directly downloaded from the website. I also noticed that my endpoint configuration isn't saved properly, or not always...

Comment: I'm also pointing out that the "Core" tab is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The properties should appear when you click on the big 'Resource' blok. You can also right click this and select 'Show Properties View'

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Java 10?

I had the same problem. I don't think Developer Studio supports that.

Try going back to Java 8 (JDK 1.8) and it should work just fine. At least that did it for me. :)

Answer (score -2):

As far as i see there is no issues with the eclipse DEV studio, once you have added the API you need to drag and drop one of the mediators only then you can see the properties tab below.
[image]

Before

After

[image]

Comment: The resource itself also has properties, these have nothing to do with any of the mediators